# Issue after executing a command with exec

Tags: node.js, bash, express

I have a problem with my node js code. I am trying to execute the follow command line:

job[command]: /Synology/server_PRGdb/models/../drago2.sh -f files/1465414445422/CNL.fasta -hmm /Synology/server_PRGdb/models/../HMMs -o analyses/1465414445422/drago2.txt > analyses/1465414445422/PutativeGenes.txt

The output file (PutativeGenes.txt) is created correctly but, It is giving me an error going in to the conditional error always and as a results of this, it does not continue with the rest of my code. Why this is happening? I have attached my code and the error message. Many thanks!!

```
command = exec(job["command"], function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(error);
    if(error){
        console.log(stderr);
    }else{
        drago2Model.updateID(job["id"], 1);

        if (job["email"] != "") { //user defined mail in the form
          smtpTransport.sendMail({ //sending mail
            from: "DRACMAGIC 2",
            to: job["email"],
            subject: "DRACMAGIC 2 analysis",
            text: "Your DRACMAGIC 2 analysis with ID " + job["id"] + " has finished.",
            attachments: [
                {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
                    path: appDir+"/analyses/"+job["id"]+"/PutativeGenes.txt"
                }
            ]
            }, function(err, response) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Email (" + job["email"] + ") from DRACMAGIC 2 analysis " + job["id"] + " could not be sent.");
              }
            }
          );
        }
        isJobExecuted = 0;
    }

  });
```

Error:

```
 { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c   /Synology/server_PRGdb/models/../drago2.sh -f files/1465414445422/CNL.fasta -hmm  /Synology/server_PRGdb/models/../HMMs -o analyses/1465414445422/drago2.txt >   analyses/1465414445422/PutativeGenes.txt
  66 sequences    71159 aas     1300 in coil
 ]
 killed: false,
 code: 1,
 signal: null,
 cmd: '/bin/sh -c /Synology/server_PRGdb/models/../drago2.sh -f    files/1465414445422/CNL.fasta -hmm /Synology/server_PRGdb/models/../HMMs -o analyses/1465414445422/drago2.txt > analyses/1465414445422/PutativeGenes.txt' }
```